# I need to remove an object from an array and display a message upon conditions

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I need a user to input 2 objects in the array. If a duplicate entry is found on the number of the flight, an alert should happen. The issue is, that the alert prevents a user from entering a certain input BUT it still adds both inputs to the array even after the alert, causing the total number of miles to be wrong. The duplicate doesn't show up in the table which is good.

Upon submission of another button, the user's level is supposed to be displayed but it displays nothing. I don't know if its because of the first issue or not.

I have tried to use pop() and splice() and it produced more errors.

```js
var total = 0;

const flightTable = document.getElementById('flightTable'),
    button = document.getElementById('display'),
    flightNum = document.getElementById('flightNumber'),
    milesFlown = document.getElementById('milesFlown'),
    addRow = () => {
        const tr = document.createElement('tr'),
            tdFlightNo = document.createElement('td'),
            tdMilesFlown = document.createElement('td');

        tdMilesFlown.setAttribute('class', 'needsToBeCounted');

        /** getting the last record in the flight objects array **/
        tdFlightNo.textContent = flightArray[i - 1].flightNumber;
        tdMilesFlown.textContent = flightArray[i - 1].milesFlown;

        /** append the TDs elements to the TR element (all of them are created above dynamically) **/
        tr.append(tdFlightNo, tdMilesFlown);

        /** append that row to the HTML table **/
        flightTable.appendChild(tr);
    }

let flightArray = [],
    flightNumValue = null,
    milesFlownValue = null,
    i = 0;

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    flightNumValue = flightNum.value;
    milesFlownValue = milesFlown.value;

    /** checking for duplicate entry **/
    if (flightArray.find(el => {
            return el.flightNumber === flightNumValue
        })) {

        alert('You cannot enter this flight due to Duplicate Flight Number entry: "' + flightNumValue + '"');
        
        return false;
    }
    
    /** add the entry in the flight objects table **/
    flightArray[i++] = {
        flightNumber: flightNumValue,
        milesFlown: milesFlownValue
    }; /** add the flight record to the array and increment the counter i (notice the i++) **/   
    addRow(); /** call addRow to add a new row in the table (HTML) **/
});

function getClassStatus() {
    var cls = document.getElementById("flightTable").getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++) {
        if (cls[i].className == "needsToBeCounted") {
            total += isNaN(cls[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(cls[i].innerHTML);
        }
        console.log(total);
        //document.getElementById("classMessages").innerHTML = total +" miles";
        document.getElementById("classMessages").innerHTML = "is the total amount of miles you have flown";
        document.getElementById("totalNoOfMiles").value = Number(total);
        console.log(total);

        displayMessage();
    }

    function displayMessage() {
        var totalValue = document.getElementsByName('totalNoOfMiles');

        var bMessageTag = document.getElementById("bMessage");
        var sMessageTag = document.getElementById("gMessage")
        var gMessageTag = document.getElementById("sMessage");
        if (totalValue < 10000) {
            bMessageTag.innerHTML = "You are a Bronze member."
            document.getElementById('sMessage').innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById('gMessage').innerHTML = "";
            console.log(bMessageTag);
        }
        if (totalValue >= 10000 && total <= 24999) {
            sMessageTag.innerHTML = "You are a Silver member."
            document.getElementById('gMessage').innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById('sMessage').innerHTML = "";

        }
        if (totalValue > 25000) {
            gMessageTag.innerHTML = "You are a Gold member."
            document.getElementById('sMessage').innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById('bMessage').innerHTML = "";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="attention">
    <label>Please enter your flight Number:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="flightNumber" name="flightnumber" value="" /> 
    <br />
    <label>Please enter Miles Flown:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="milesFlown" name="milesflown" value="" />
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="display" name="display" value="Submit Flight Information" />
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="status" name="status" value="Get Class Level" onclick=getClassStatus(); />
    <br>
    <input type="number" id="totalNoOfMiles" name="totalNoOfMiles" value="" />

    <div id="classMessages"></div>
    <h3>Your Passenger Class Level is:</h3>
    <div id="bMessage"></div>
    <div id="sMessage"></div>
    <div id="gMessage"></div>

    <table id="flightTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Flight Number</th>
            <th>Number of Miles</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

When a user enters in two inputs, the inputs should be displayed in a table after clicking a button to submit the info. For a user to get its' "level" they should click another button. Their level displays based on the sum of one of their inputs(miles). The levels should change dynamically depending on their level. A duplicate entry on flight # can not be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You total accumulator is always appending to the total so the total number of miles will forever grow.

Your messages are not displaying because values stored from `type="text"` inputs will always be a string where later you compare string to number. Strings are compared character by character until they are not equal or there aren't any characters left to compare. What you need is numeric comparison so `number < number` is a more accurate expression for your logic.

**Let's get to it...**

When a user adds flight information we can acquire both flight no. and miles. We want to save the miles as a numeric value as such:

```
milesFlownValue = Number(milesFlown.value);
```

Instead of declaring an iterator, you could push each object to `flightArray`...

```
flightArray.push({
  flightNumber: flightNumValue,
  milesFlown: milesFlownValue
});
```

You can then use the size of this array to a) check if the array has any elements to execute logic on and b) if so, you can execute tests using [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which works great for conditional statements. Notice in the below conditional that `toLowerCase()` is vital because you'll want flight numbers like `A123` and `a123` to be the same thing.

```
if (flightArray.length &&
    flightArray.some(entry => entry.flightNumber.toLowerCase() === flightNumValue.toLowerCase()) ) {
  ...
}
```

Now when you add a new row, there's no `pop()` or `slice()` needed because you're not wanting to change the state of the original array. You can simply get the last item the traditional way...

```
lastItem = flightArray[flightArray.length - 1]
```

The rest is pretty straight forward but I've improved some code that I'm hoping you'll benefit from.

```js
const flightTable = document.getElementById('flightTable'),
      button = document.getElementById('display'),
      flightNum = document.getElementById('flightNumber'),
      milesFlown = document.getElementById('milesFlown'),
      status = document.getElementById('status'),
      classLevel = document.getElementById("classLevel");

const addRow = () => {
  const tr = document.createElement('tr'),
        tdFlightNo = document.createElement('td'),
        tdMilesFlown = document.createElement('td'),
        lastItem = flightArray[flightArray.length - 1];

  tdFlightNo.textContent = lastItem.flightNumber;
  tdMilesFlown.textContent = lastItem.milesFlown;
  tr.append(tdFlightNo, tdMilesFlown);

  flightTable.appendChild(tr);
}

let flightArray = [],
    flightNumValue = null,
    milesFlownValue = null,
    total = 0;

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  flightNumValue = flightNum.value;
  milesFlownValue = Number(milesFlown.value);

  if (flightArray.length && flightArray.some(entry => entry.flightNumber.toLowerCase() === flightNumValue.toLowerCase())) {
    alert('You cannot enter this flight due to Duplicate Flight Number entry: "' + flightNumValue + '"');
    return false;
  }

  flightArray.push({
    flightNumber: flightNumValue,
    milesFlown: milesFlownValue
  });

  addRow();
});


status.addEventListener('click', () => {
  total = flightArray.reduce((a, b) => a + b.milesFlown, 0)
  document.getElementById("classMessages").innerHTML = `${total} is the total amount of miles you have flown`;
  displayMessage();
})

function displayMessage() {
  let output = "";

  if (total > 0 && total < 10000) {
    output = "You are a Bronze member.";
  }
  else if (total >= 10000 && total <= 24999) {
    output = "You are a Silver member.";
  }
  else if (total > 25000) {
    output = "You are a Gold member.";
  }
  classLevel.textContent = output;
}
```

```html
<form name="attention">
  <label>Please enter your flight Number:</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="flightNumber" name="flightnumber" value="" /> 
  <br />
  <label>Please enter Miles Flown:</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="milesFlown" name="milesflown" value="" />
  <br />
  <input type="button" id="display" name="display" value="Submit Flight Information" />
  <br />
  <input type="button" id="status" name="status" value="Get Class Level" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <div id="classMessages"></div>
  <div id="classLevel"></div>
  <br />
  <table id="flightTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Flight Number</th>
      <th>Number of Miles</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```